# Removing duplicates for both values

Tags: c++, algorithm

My special case: home project, automatic downloader for podcasts.

Overall algorithm is:

1. Download a list of available podcasts
2. hash the podcasts
3. load metadata + hash of downloaded podcasts from sqlite db
4. Algorithm this questions is about -  throw out all already downloaded.
5. Download new podcasts
6. save metadata to sqlite db

[Algorithm discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495409/c-algorithm-remove-duplicates-both-values)

I'm hoping for comments on using `std::rotate`, performance, and the implementation.

For downloaded data, I currently use a vector. For data from DB, I also use a vector.

I merge both together and sort them according to the hashes (obviously).

And algorithm `doubleEraser` on the merged vector.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

template <typename ForwardItr>
ForwardItr doubleEraser(ForwardItr first, ForwardItr last)
{
 auto itr = first;
 typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardItr>::value_type firstMatch = *first;
 bool hasFirstMatch(false);

 while(itr != last)
 {
  auto next = std::next(itr);
  if(next != last && *itr == *next)
  {
    if(!hasFirstMatch)
    {
     hasFirstMatch = true;
     firstMatch = *itr;
    }
    else
    {
     if(*itr == firstMatch) // again at first match
     {
       return itr; 
     }
    }


    std::rotate(itr, std::next(itr, 2), last); // throw matched elements to the end of container
   }
   else
    ++itr;
  }
 return last;
}

template <typename T>
void print(T& c)
{
 for(auto & element : c)
  std::cout << element << " ";

 std::cout << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void process(std::vector<T>& t)
{
  std::string formating(" \t");
   std::cout << "input: " << formating;
 print(t);
 std::sort(t.begin(), t.end());
 std::cout << "sorted:" << formating;
 print(t);
 auto itr_begin = doubleEraser(t.begin(), t.end());
 std::cout << "dEraser:" << formating;
 print(t);
 t.erase(itr_begin, t.end());
 std::cout << "output:" << formating;
 print(t);
}

int main()
{
 std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,5,6,7,2};
 std::vector<char> vec2 {'A', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'A' };
 std::vector<std::string> vec3 {"Hello", "World", "that", "be", "that", "Hello"};

 process(vec);
 process(vec2);
 process(vec3);
}
```

Comment: Are you actually starting with two sets or one? Your text description sounds like you have two, but your code has only one set.

Comment: i expanded the discription:
For downloaded data i currently us a vector.

For data from DB i use a vector, too.

I merge both together, i sort it according to the hashes (obviously).

And algorithm doubleEraser on the merged vector.

Comment: Don't merge them; sort them separately and then use `std::set_difference`.

Answer (score 1):

Comment by @T.C.:

Don't merge them; sort them separately and then use `std::set_difference`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void print(T& c)
{
 for(auto & element : c)
  std::cout << element << " ";

 std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
 std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,6,7,8};
 std::vector<int> vec4 {3,4,5,6};
 std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
 std::sort(vec4.begin(), vec4.end());
std::set_difference(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec4.begin(), vec4.end(), std::inserter(vec5, vec5.begin()));
 print(vec5);
}
```

- Input: {1,2,3,4,6,7,8} and {3,4,5,6}
- Output wanted: 1,2,5,7,8
- Output real: 1,2,7,8

You cannot use `std::set_difference` because of the hashes used as comparison criteria. The Hash Distribution of new hashes is not sortable in a way that new items will be the last ones, which is a requirement for `std::set_difference`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you have a set of "available" (`{1,2,3,4,6,7,8}`) and a set of "downloaded" (`{3,4,5,6}`), right? And you want the set of "available but not downloaded", which is, correctly, `{1,2,7,8}`. `{1,2,5,7,8}` would be both "available but not downloaded" and "downloaded but not available". If you really want that, there's `std::set_symmetric_difference`.

Answer (score 1):

1. If `std::set_difference` or `std::set_symmetric_difference` work for you, then just use those.
2. Else if you have to merge the vectors for some reason, I would recommend replacing `doubleEraser()` with something like this:

   ```
   template <typename ForwardItr>
   ForwardItr remove_adjacent (ForwardItr first, ForwardItr last)
   {
       while ((first = std::adjacent_find (first, last)) != last) {
           auto value = *first ;
           last = std::remove (first, last, value) ;
       }

       return last ;
   }
   ```

   You already sort `t` before you call `doubleEraser()`, so this should always work. It also handles the case when you have more than just two duplicates.
3. If the above for some reason does not fit your requirements, then below is a small review of your `doubleEraser()` function.

   ```
   typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardItr>::value_type firstMatch = *first;
   ```

   Could just be:

   ```
   auto firstMatch = *first;
   ```

   The performance of `std::rotate()` should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll use std::set_ algorithms. Ad 2.) Check your algorithm Given Input:
1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 --sort--- remove_adjacent output:
1 2 4 6 7 8 <--- 4, 6 are illegal numbers. It jumps after it found one dup pair.

Comment: Needs to make a copy of `*first` for `remove()` - `auto val = *first; last = std::remove (first, last, val);`. Otherwise weird things happens since `remove` takes the value by const reference, which changes during the process of removal.